# Mimsy were the Borogoves - why is "mimsy" an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech

I'm reading Lewis Carroll's *"Through the Looking-Glass"* and I've found a famous poem *Jabberwocky*:

> Twas bryllyg, and the slythy toves
>   Did gyre and gymble in the wabe:
>   All mimsy were the borogoves;
>   And the mome raths outgrabe.

I've read some articles about that poem. All of them (for instance, [this one](http://peelweb.org/admin/data/articles_bogus/bj0013.htm)) say that *mimsy* is an adjective, but they don't say why. I can't  make head nor tail of the syntax of this sentence.

For example, a sentence with similar structure might look like this:

> All gray were the wolves

But I guess that it is an incorrect form, and the correct form is:

> All the gray ones were the wolves

So, is the form of using an adjective in the example above really correct? And why it can't be a noun (i.e. like in *all wolves were the animals*)? I really can't understand it.

Comment: It sounds like an adjective since it ends with a 'y'.

Comment: All sleepy were the wolves

Comment: [mimsy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mimsy) is an adjective: *Rather feeble and prim or affected.*  And there's nothing wrong with the syntax of that sentence, assuming that "borogoves" is a noun.  It's a simple inversion of a "to be" sentence, like "All sweaty were the workmen."

Comment: "All gray were the wolves" is technically correct, and "All the gray ones were the wolves" sounds even more strange to my ears, and conveys a different meaning (although, without context, both are fairly nonsensical to me).

Comment: Your example with "All grey were the wolves" becoming "All the grey ones were wolves" is incorrect. "All grey were the wolves" is just a simple inversion, and means "All the wolves were grey", not "All grey things were wolves."

Comment: *"I can't make head nor tail of the syntax of this sentence"* ... well, it *is* a nonsense verse, after all...  :-)

Comment: "all gray were the wolves" is a poetic form of saying "the wolves were gray" - Carroll is just saying that "the borogroves were mimsy"...

Comment: @Simba: The syntax of nonsense is actually in my experience usually straightforward, enabling the semantics to be all the more effectively paradoxical or absurd.

Comment: @simba wait till you get to the next line after the mimsy one!  "And the mome raths outgrabe"

Comment: Humpty Dumpty openly explains the word mimsy as 'flimsy and miserable' in the book

Comment: @DavidRicherby Personally, I read "all gray were the wolves" as an inversion of "the wolves were all gray", so "the borogoves were all mimsy".

Comment: I don't understand why this question wasn't closed at once. The word actually appears in various dictionaries now.

Comment: For a rather different theory, check out Kuttner and Moore's ["Mimsy Were The Borogoves"](http://jabberwockland.blogspot.com/2007/03/mimsy-were-borogoves-by-lewis-padgett.html).

Answer (score 139, accepted):

At the suggestion of the kind commenter, let me discuss the syntax of

> All mimsy were the borogoves

There are two possibilities. The first is that *mimsy* is a noun, in which case we have the structure

> Subject Copulative-Verb Predicate-Complement

where

Subject = Noun Phrase *All mimsy*
Copulative Verb = *were*
Predicate Complement = Noun Phrase *the borogoves*

This pattern would obtain for recognizable nouns thusly:

> All priests were the granters of indulgences.

The second possibility is that *mimsy* is an adjective. Ordinarily we would expect the same word order when the complement is an adjective, i.e.,

> The borogoves were all mimsy

but it's possible to invert the order and put the adjectival complement *all mimsy* first, i.e., to have the order

> Predicate-Complement Copulative Verb Subject

In recognizable words:

> All rosy were the cheeks of the children.

This is a recognizably poetic style. Consider the lines from Walt Whitman's *Leaves of Grass*:

> Brave, **brave were the soldiers** (high named to-day) who lived 
>   through the fight;
>   But the bravest press'd to the front and fell, unnamed, unknown.

In ordinary prose, we'd say "the soldiers were brave".

At the prompt of a second kind commenter, let me note that the modifier *all* doesn't help us figure out whether to choose noun or adjective for *mimsy*. (Perhaps this part of the sly whimsy of the Deacon Dodgson.) If we're thinking noun, then *all* is an acceptable as a universal **determinative**, as in

> **All** soldiers are brave.

If we lean toward adjective, then *all* is acceptable as an **adverbial** modifier, as in

> We are **all** excited.

(Note the ambiguity. In an intensifying role -- *We are all very excited* -- the Ngram viewer finds few examples in the 19th century, and it seems to be an American colloquialism. The universal role -- *We are all of us excited* -- is common and earlier.)

To decide, consider the following common<sup>*</sup> English adjectives, most<sup>‡</sup> of which are formed by adding the suffix *-y* to the related noun ending in *s*/*se* to get an adjectival form: *ease*->*eas**y***, *nose*->*nos**y***, etc.

> antsy artsy backwoodsy bitsy blousy blowsy<sup>1</sup> bluesy booksy bossy bousy<sup>2</sup>
>   brassy busy<sup>3</sup> cheesy choosy citrusy classy clumsy<sup>4</sup> cosy<sup>5</sup> creasy cutesy<sup>6</sup>
>   ditsy dressy drowsy<sup>7</sup> easy flimsy<sup>8</sup> flossy folksy fussy gassy
>   glassy glossy gneissy goosy grassy greasy gutsy hissy kissy
>   lossy lousy messy minstrelsy mossy mousy mussy newsy noisy nosy
>   outdoorsy primrosy prissy queasy<sup>9</sup> rosy sassy sudsy teensy<sup>10</sup> tipsy tricksy
>   weensy<sup>11</sup> woodsy wussy

Now compare this to a list of common<sup>**</sup> English nouns ending in *-sy*:

> apostasy autopsy biopsy catalepsy controversy courtesy curtsy daisy
>   dropsy dyspepsy ecstasy embassy epilepsy fantasy footsy geodesy gypsy heresy
>   hypocrisy hypostasy idiosyncrasy isostasy jealousy leprosy narcolepsy
>   necropsy palsy pansy pleurisy poesy pussy speakeasy whimsy

The countable nouns require a **plural** form to go with the determinative *all* and the plural verb *were*:

> *All* **autopsies** *were* performed by the coroner.
>   *All* **fantasies** *were* repressed by the patients.

and so on. The noncountable nouns in the singular can take the preceding *all*, but they require a *singular* verb:

> All **fantasy** *is* meaningless.
>   All **courtesy** *is* hypocritical.

Given the distribution favoring adjectives of words ending in *-sy*, the lexical likelihood of finding a related noun, the syntactic constraints on number, and the fact that this is a poem, where the subject/adjectival-complement order may be inverted, a fluent English speaker will consider that *mimsy* is an adjective meaning having the qualities of a *mim*, some noun unknown.

---

*I obtained my list [here](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/ends_with.php). Since I edited the results, and I'm going to argue by weight of vocabulary, I need to reveal my method. I avoided double counting by excluding some words formed by prefixing (e.g., ***a***acatalepsy, ***dis***courtesy, ***non***drowsy, ***over***busy, ***re***biopsy, ***ultra***glossy, ***un***easy).

**I eliminated technical (mostly medical) terms (*biorhexistasy*,
*cholecystolithotripsy*, *cholelithotripsy*, *dyschromatopsy*,
*glacioisostasy*, *hemiachromatopsy*, *hemichromatopsy*, *hypnolepsy*, *lithotripsy*, *nephrolithotripsy*).

‡ Those not related to common nouns are noted in the numbered notes, the content of which is from the *OED*. Those which have no known candidates for related nouns are in ***bold italic***.

1. *blowsy* coarse and flushed. From *blowze*, a bloated slattern
2. *bousy* drunk. From *bouse*, liquor or a drinking bout
3. **busy** No known related noun, from the Old English adjective *besig*
4. *clumsy* probably from the now-obsolete *clumse*, eventually from a Scandinavian word meaning to benumb with cold. It had a number of pejorative uses as an adjective and an attributive noun.
5. ***cosy*** "derivation unknown"
6. ***cutesy*** No noun, from *cute*, an adjective
7. *drowsy* From *drowse*, a fit of sleepiness, itself from the verb of the same spelling
8. *flimsy* Derivation uncertain. The claim of *film* seems like folk etymology, especially given the adjective *filmy*. But the word *flim* is preserved as a fossil in *flim-flam*, and it’s possibly related to an Old Norse word *flim* meaning a mockery or lampoon.
9. ***queasy*** "Of obscure history"
10. *teensy* Likely from the obsolete *tine*, very small or something very small
11. ***weensy*** No related noun. Likely from *wee* and a rhyme with *teensy*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48314/discussion-on-answer-by-deadrat-mimsy-were-the-borogoves-why-is-mimsy-an-adj). If there are elements in moved comments and subsequent chat that belong in this answer, then such elements should be edited into this answer not left as ephemera.

Comment: ᴍᴏᴅᴇʀᴀᴛᴏʀ ɴᴏᴛᴇ: Comments **cannot be moved to chat a second time**.  Please use [this posting’s chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48314/discussion-on-answer-by-deadrat-mimsy-were-the-borogoves-why-is-mimsy-an-adj) for discussion. Further comments here will be deleted.

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286907/102937)

Answer (score 42):

Later in the book, Humpty Dumpty gives Alice an explanation of the odd words in the poem and he defines 'mimsy' as 'miserable and flimsy'. In other words, we know it is an adjective because Lewis Carroll intended it to be one.

Comment: I don’t think this is the whole answer.  Most native English-speakers will understand *mimsy* to be an adjective on first reading the poem, without reading Carroll’s/Humpty’s explanation of it.  Carroll’s/Humpty’s explanation confirms that this understanding really is the intended one — but it doesn’t explain why it’s the natural reading of the sentence.

Comment: "When *I* use a word," Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less."' Since Humpty Dumpty's meanings of words were explicitly personal, there could be other interpretations.  Why not *mime and whimsy*, which can both be nouns?

Comment: I just realized that my own mental definition of it that I've had as a child (small and petty) was probably from miniature and whimsy. Huh. But OP is right, I never questioned but that it was adjectival.

Comment: One of the points of the poem is to demonstrate how we easily understand grammar and word types even when the words are nonsense. No one needs to tell us what *mimsy* specifically means to infer that it's an adjective.

Answer (score 28):

Fortunately, Carroll's own definition assigns the part of speech to 'mimsy'. Otherwise, the word might now be taken as an early and unprecedented appearance of the British regional 'mimsy', also an adjective, but with a somewhat different meaning, although latterly sometimes influenced by Carroll's coinage:

> Prim; careful; affected; feeble, weak, lightweight.
>
> ["mimsy, adj.2 (and adv.)". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/255344 (accessed November 08, 2016).]

This 'mimsy' is attested first in 1880; the etymology is given:

> Apparently < MIM *adj.* + *-sy* (in CLUMSY *adj.*, FLIMSY *adj.*, TIPSY *adj.*, etc.). Compare MIMSY *adj.*<sup>1</sup>, by which this word appears sometimes to be influenced.
>
> (op. cit.)

The first part of the compound, 'mim', has a much earlier provenance, first appearing around 1586, and attested through 1991. It is also an adjective (and adverb), used regionally in Scottish and British English:

> Reserved or restrained in manner or behaviour, esp. in a contrived or priggish way; affectedly modest, demure; primly silent, quiet; affectedly moderate or abstemious in diet (*rare*). Also (occas.) of a person's appearance.
>
> ["mim, adj. and adv.". OED Online. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/118631 (accessed November 08, 2016).]

However, Carroll himself was kind enough to differentiate between his 'mimsy' and the British regional 'mimsy'. As Humpty Dumpty explained to Alice, 'mimsy' is a portmanteau of 'flimsy' and 'miserable' ([*Through the Looking Glass*](http://literature.org/authors/carroll-lewis/through-the-looking-glass/chapter-06.html), 1871):

> Exactly so. Well, then, "mimsy" is "flimsy and miserable" (there's another portmanteau for you).

The portmanteau clearly amounts to something akin to 'unhappy', but if there was any doubt, that meaning is made explicit in Carroll's gloss of the first verse of "Jabberwocky", first published in Carroll's own literary magazine, *Mischmasch*, in 1855.

As mentioned by Carroll's nephew, Stuart Collingwood, who provides a facsimile of part of the gloss in an article in *The Strand Magazine* (["Before 'Alice' — The Boyhood of Lewis Carroll"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=chi.42678600;view=1up;seq=624;size=150), 1899, p. 616), Carroll himself defined the eleven words in the verse that were not "pure, honest English":

> [image: facsimile of gloss for Jabberwocky]
>
> (op. cit.)

Collingwood's account gives the rest of Carroll's gloss, and also supplies a complete 'translation' of the first sentence (continuing from the facsimile):

> [image: gloss continued]
>   [image: gloss finished, plus 'translation']

The evidence from the 1855 *Mischmasch*, along with the evidence given by Humpty Dumpty in the 1871 *Through the Looking Glass*, leaves no doubt that 'mimsy' is an adjective. Without that evidence, 'mimsy' could well be a noun, verb or even a subdued interjection in poetic use.

Comment: It's interesting that many of Collingwood's definitions are different from the ones given by Carroll via Humpty Dumpty in Looking Glass. Perhaps Carroll changed them to make them more humorous and more accessible to children as he wrote the book. I also wonder whether 'gyaour' is supposed to be pronounced with a hard 'g' rather than the soft one derived from gyroscope. This would give the alliteration favoured by many performers when speaking the line '...did gyre and gimble in the wabe' and which is at odds with the Humpty definition of 'to go round and round like a gyuroscope'

Comment: Interesting that so many of us read 'borogove' as 'borogrove' (I say 'us' because I've done it myself). Even Collingwood makes the error.

Comment: When I changed my name, I came perilously close to winding up as "Borogrove"; an extremely literate and pedantic friend caught the error just in time. The error is natural; "-grove/-greave" and "-grave" (two unrelated etymologies, apparently) are not-uncommon suffixes in English, while "-gove" is not.

Answer (score 20):

Something that hasn't been mentioned yet: "all" here is being used as an adverb.  Some examples of common English phrases using this construction:

- all worked up (thoroughly excited or upset e.g. *"She got all worked up at the idea of adopting a baby."*)
- all right (meaning in a satisfactory manner or to a satisfactory extent)
- all ready/all set (meaning "fully prepared", e.g. *"Toby, are you all ready for school?"*

So, "the bogoroves were all mimsy" comes across as meaning "the bogoroves were *thoroughly* mimsy".  Certainly, this is the construction that makes the most sense to a native ear.

Comment: I am sorry to see that this essential and, to me, obvious point has so few votes.

Comment: @PJTraill the question had been up for almost a day when I put this here, so I'm not expecting much.  And of course no one has the time to scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page :P.

Comment: I know the feeling.

Comment: With a closer reading, it seems the top answer does eventually address this point.

Comment: Only after I pointed out your answer, which he has now upvoted.

Comment: In most uses of this adverbial "all" (besides the set phrases given in this answer), it feels to me highly informal, and even like it is akin to that stigmatized interjection, "like" -- in fact, in most cases I can think of where someone says "[noun] was all [adjective]", I can easily imagine it being "[noun] was, like, all [adjective]" without the tone, register, formality, etc. changing. Does anyone know whether this "all" was informal to this extent (or even at all) in the varieties of English which Carroll was imitating?

Answer (score 13):

To add to the other answers...

The poem is a pastiche of heroic poetry such as *Beowulf*.  This inversion is generally seen by native English speakers as old-fashioned/archaic.  There are many other archaic constructions in the poem too - just in that first verse, "**twas** midnight" and "the slithy toves **did** gyre" are forms which were no longer in use in spoken English at the time Carroll wrote it.

Whilst this is amusing in its own right, it's also a dig at the Victorian poets who were (in all seriousness) writing heroic poetry and using these archaic constructions to try to add gravitas to their writing.  Edward Lear did the same with some of his nonsense rhymes - [The Cummerbund](http://fileserver.net-texts.com/asset.aspx?dl=no&id=42224) is a prime example, although Lear took it a step further by using genuine words.  (Look up the actual meanings for the Indian words referenced!)

Comment: very nice, but i take exception to the use of "did". at least in American speech it's quite acceptable to use this form to add stress. for example, a teacher asks, "you didn't read the book, did you?" and the student can respond, "i did read the book".

Comment: Fair point, although that's the modern use as an intensifier and particularly as a rebuttal.  I believe Carroll was using it in its older sense as simply a form of the past tense, though - I don't see anyone saying "those slithy toves weren't gyring" which the author needed to contradict. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you embed the sentence as a complement, you have to change the word order:

```
*Henry thought that all mimsy were the borogoves.  
Henry thought that the borogoves were all mimsy.
```

This tells us that the original example has had its subject inverted, because subject-verb inversion applies only in root (unembedded) clauses.  So we know that "the borogoves" is subject, and "were" agrees in number with that subject:

```
The borogoves were all mimsy.
```

If "mimsy" were a predicate noun, it would have to agree in number with the subject "the borogoves".  Compare with a familiar noun:

```
*The houses were cottage.  
The houses were cottages.
```

But adjectives in English do not have a distinct plural form,

```
*The houses were shuttereds.  
The houses were shuttered.
```

So if mimsy were a noun, the original example would have had to be

```
The borogoves were all mimsies.
```

"Mimsy" must be an adjective, since it doesn't agree in number with the subject.

Comment: The singular of 'mimsy' (plural noun) is perhaps 'moumsy' (on the loose model of 'mouse' > 'mice').

Answer (score 1):

It's an example of poetic inversion.   "The borogroves were all mimsy" wouldn't trouble you.  Mimsy is an attribute of the borogroves.   Writing it backwards makes no difference.

"The sky was blue"
"Blue was the sky".

Poets (and Yoda) like doing that sort of thing.